# Selecting more features with "ILIKE" and "IN" operators using QGIS

Tags: qgis, select-by-attribute, select-by-expression

I would like to select more features with expression in a specific field, which contains the name of the attribute (`IN` operator is useful). Moreover, the name could not be exact, so the `ILIKE` operator is necessary.

How can I match these 2 operators in one expression?

For example, I need to select 2 city called *'Rome'* and *'New York'*.

```
"city" in ('Rome','New York') -> selected both
"city" in ('rom','new yor') -> not selected
```

Any suggestion to select in the second case in QGIS?

Comment: The `select by expression` uses its own non-SQL syntax

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this task using arrays.

1. Create an array with the search themes AND the placeholders
2. for each value of the array, find if the `name` column contains it or not, using `ilike`
3. as the output of step 2 is an array of true/false values, check if this output contains at least 1 true result

```sql
array_contains(
    array_foreach( 
        ARRAY('%rom%','new yor%'),
        name ilike @element),
true)
```

Comment: How can i select, using the expression, the records which cannot contain '%rom%','new yor%'? 
Replacing true with false and using "not ilike" it doesn't work. 
I need the invert selection of the otuput. Thanks!

Comment: @Mark keep the same expression and add `NOT ` in front

Answer (score 1):

Additionally you may try using [`regexp_match()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html#string-functions) function

```
regexp_match("City", '((?i)new yor|(?i)rom)')
```

The result of this query will select 'Rome' and 'New York' including their derivatives, see image below

[image: result]

---

**References:**

- https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/resources/function_help/json/regexp_match