# Selecting two or more values (like two city names) in one column

Tags: qgis-3, attribute-table, select-by-attribute, filter

In the attribute table I have a column with many cities and want to select rows that only contain these city names, like `"Paris"` and `"London"`.
I tried: `"cityname" ILIKE 'Paris' OR 'London'` but it doesn't seem to work.

I have seen a reply using `"arrays"` to a similar question but I am not sure how it works and I would prefer to use ilike if possible.

[Selecting more features with the "ilike" and "in" operator using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/363553/selecting-more-features-with-the-ilike-and-in-operator-using-qgis)

Comment: Have you tried `"cityname" in ('Paris', 'London')`?

Comment: Or `"cityname" ILIKE 'Paris' OR "cityname" ILIKE  'London'`?

Comment: Or `"cityname" LIKE 'Paris' OR "cityname" LIKE 'London'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to write the name of the field and the `ILIKE` again after the `OR`.

```sql
"cityname" ILIKE 'Paris' OR "cityname" ILIKE 'London'
```