# Selecting features based on great number of different values in the Attribute Table

Tags: qgis-3, attribute-table, filter

I have many land parcels related to many different cities. I would like to select land parcels related to some of these cities only (about 20 of them).

Is using `LIKE/ILIKE + OR` like below the only way to do this or is there a faster and more elegant way to do it when dealing?

`'ILIKE'`-way:

```sql
"city" ILIKE 'Paris' 
or
"city" ILIKE 'Rome' 
or
"city" ILIKE 'Berlin' 
or
"city" ILIKE 'Moscow'
```

Maybe in the form? But just writing `'Paris' OR 'Rome' or 'Berlin' or 'Moscow'` in the `"city"` field doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Please, inspect carefully the comments left in [your previous question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/372242/selecting-two-or-more-values-like-two-city-names-in-one-column), mainly one from @ahmadhanb, i.e. `"city" in ('Paris', 'London', 'Berlin', ...)` is your faster and more elegant solution.

Comment: Thank you! I was about to say I had found "city" = 'Paris' or "city" = 'London' or... but this is even better indeed.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer is to write:

```sql
"city" in ('Paris', 'London', 'Berlin'...)
```

Thank you to @ahmadhanb and @taras